# Javascript - Array.isArray with JSON Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

In my **Javascript** code, I have an `if` condition in my method that check if the parameters is an Array:

```
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        return true;
    }

  return null;
```

The **value** is a `JSONArray` like this:

```
[{title: "james", author: "potter"}]
```

But always return null.

> Is a JSONArray from Java, I am using Nashorn at Java 8 that allows you
>   tu call Javascript methods from Java code.

**What type should I use to return true?**

Comment: Can't reproduce. `Array.isArray([{title: "james", author: "potter"}]) === true`

Comment: No it does not. What is `value` exactly? We need a [mcve]!

Comment: There is no such thing as a `JSONArray` in JavaScript. Either is JSON (i.e. a string) or an array. Read about [the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if `(Array.isArray (JSON.parse (value))) {return true;}`

Comment: This will return "org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject" on Android